# How to subset matrices in a list based on another list with values indicating column numbers

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I have a list of matrices (mat_list). I want to create a new list with a selected subset of columns from each matrix. I have another list of numerics (col_list) which indicates column numbers to keep.
Example dataset:

```
> mat_list <- list(structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3"))),structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3")))) ; names(mat_list) <- c("mat1","mat2")
> mat_list
$mat1
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  1  5  9
[2,]  2  6 10
[3,]  3  7 11
[4,]  4  8 12

$mat2
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  1  5  9
[2,]  2  6 10
[3,]  3  7 11
[4,]  4  8 12

> col_list <- list(structure(c(1,3)),structure(c(2,3))) ; names(col_list) <- c("var1","var2")
> col_list
$var1
[1] 1 3

$var2
[1] 2 3
```

I would like the following output:

```
> my_list
$mat1
     V1 V3
[1,]  1  9
[2,]  2  10
[3,]  3  11
[4,]  4  12

$mat2
     V2 V3
[1,]  5  9
[2,]  6 10
[3,]  7 11
[4,]  8 12
```

I've tried to use lapply to subset these columns across all the matrices. The closest I've gotten is to do

```
> lapply(mat_list,function(x) x[,col_list$var1])
$mat1
     V1 V3
[1,]  1  9
[2,]  2 10
[3,]  3 11
[4,]  4 12

$mat2
     V1 V3
[1,]  1  9
[2,]  2 10
[3,]  3 11
[4,]  4 12
```

This uses the values from col$var1 applied over all matrices in mat_list. But I haven't been able to successfully apply this over all (both) the elements of col_list - e.g. by implementing lapply to var_list, something along

```
lapply(mat_list,function(x) x[,lapply(var_list)])
```

I'm grateful for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `lapply`, in this case `mapply` fits perfectly:

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[, y], mat_list, col_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

which is also equivalent to

```
Map(function(x, y) x[, y], mat_list, col_list)
```

Both approaches apply the specified function by taking corresponding arguments from `mat_list` and `col_list` at the same time.

The reason `lapply` doesn't work is that it goes only over a single variable, as you noticed. To use `lapply` one would instead need

```
lapply(seq_along(mat_list), function(i) mat_list[[i]][, col_list[[i]]])
```

Bonus: if `mat_list` contained data frames rather than matrices, one could be even more concise with

```
mapply(`[`, mat_list, col_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# or
Map(`[`, mat_list, col_list)
```